# Map Values from Column in Table A to Corresponding Column in Table B

Tags: mysql

Part 1:

In MySQL suppose I have Table A which has more columns than Table B.  I want to transfer values from Table B to Table A where the **id** row in A matches the **id** Row in B and update the values in table A from the values in table B.

Part 2:

Table B is a superset of table A, so how does one insert **ids** and their corresponding **values** from table B into table A while also updating **id**'s that are in table A.

[image]

Comment: Questions asking for code must demonstrate a minimal understanding of the problem being solved. **Include attempted solutions, why they didn't work, and the expected results.**

Answer (score 0):

Like FreshPrinceOfSO already mentioned in the comments, you won't get code for free here.

But here are at least the steps. Two possibilities. Either you split the work up in two statements, one update then one insert statement. Or you could work with

```
INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...
```

You would have to have an unique index on the table for this to work.

For the first solution mentioned you'd `inner join` the tables for the `update` first, that's trivial. Then for the `insert` you'd use a `select` with a `left join` and with `is null` checking for entries that are not already in the table.

Good luck...